# keyup function highlighting value being inputed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the below snippet when a user starts to type in the input field, the results begin to filter.

Right now I'm capturing the value. As the user types and erases I want to append the value around a span class. This way I can highlight the results as they type.

Here is what I have so far, is going the append route the best method to use?

Here is a link to jsFiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/uvcLfed6/1/

```js
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    //console.log('Value: ' + value);
    $(value).addClass("highlight");
    //$(value).css("background-color", "pink");
    $("#myDiv *").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF33; 
}
```

````html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

```
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<div id="myDiv">

  <div>
<h2>Title Here</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.<p>
<p>Some text Here</p>
  </div>

  <div>
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
<pre>
    This is some some text here
    pre tag here with content <br> Hi
</pre>
  </div>

  <div>
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>

  <div>
Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate
  </div>

</div>
```
````

Comment: Edit the snippet above :)

Comment: I'll create one now.. thanks for the advice!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uvcLfed6/1/

Answer (score 0):

With `.each` , `.replace()` you can achieve that

```js
$('#myInput').on('input',function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    // show / hide divs which contains the value
    // .hide() to hide all divs then .filter() to filter the divs contains the value then .show() it
    /*$("#myDiv > div").hide().filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1;
    }).show();*/
    
    // replace the string with `<span>`
    $("#myDiv > div").each(function() {    // loop through divs
        if($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1){ // if this div contains value
          $(this).html($(this).text().replace(new RegExp(value , "g"), '<span class="highlight">'+value+'</span>'));  // wrap the value in highlight span then change the div `html` with the new value
          $(this).show();  // show the div
        }else{  // if not contains the value
          $(this).html($(this).text()); // return the div html to the text without spans
          $(this).hide(); // hide the div
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF33; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<div id="myDiv">

  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
  </div>

  <div>
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
  </div>

  <div>
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>

  <div>
    Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate
  </div>

</div>
```

```js
$('#myInput').on('input',function() {
    var value = $(this).val().trim();
    
    $("#myDiv *").each(function(){
      var IsNested = !$(this).hasClass('toggle');
      if(IsNested === true){
        var reg = new RegExp(value , 'g');
        if($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1){
          $(this).html($(this).text().replace(reg , '<span class="highlight">'+ value +'</span>'));
        }else{
          $(this).html($(this).html().replace('<span class="highlight">' , '').replace('</span>' , ''));
        }
       }else{
        
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF33; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<div id="myDiv">

  <div class="toggle">
<h2>Title Here</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.<p>
<p>Some text Here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="toggle">
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
<pre>
    This is some some text here
    pre tag here with content <br> Hi
</pre>
  </div>

  <div class="toggle">
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>

  <div class="toggle">
Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you may want to use replace all with regexp

Comment: Thank you!! I did have a question, some of the content in ```myDiv``` is wrapped in a ```pre``` tag. Using this method it breaks the structure of the pre tag, removing all ```br``` elements. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: @hisusu32 my code is working for a direct divs inside `#mydiv` and when removing the value it change the whole div html with the div text to remove any highlighted spans that's why any tags in the divs has been removed .. it'll be better to Edit the snippet with exact case you've to get a right answer

Comment: Check that, looks like all elements are losing their attributes. I probably should have used some actual content instead, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply taking inner html as string and replace all found result with wrapped span. In this way, you can preserve html structure as well.

```js
// save structure before use
var original = $("#myDiv").html();

// bind event
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
  // get search value
  var value = $(this).val();

  // replace with original
  $("#myDiv").html(original);

  if (!value) {
    // if empty
    return;
  }

  // filter
  $("#myDiv *").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1;
  }).each(function() {
  // wrap search term in span 
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(value, "<span class='highlight'>" + value + "</span>"));
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #FFFF33;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<div id="myDiv">

  <div>
    <h2>Title Here</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
      <p>
        <p>Some text Here</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    <pre>
            This is some some text here
            pre tag here with content <br> Hi
        </pre>
  </div>

  <div>
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>

  <div>
    Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm! Is there any way to have it filter and only show the div's with results? The same way the original code was doing? Thanks

Comment: @hisusu32 yes there is. Before highlight logic simply adding a class would do the trick.